# Как проверить поддержку es 2015, 2016?

Tags: php, javascript, frontend, babel

Хочу генерировать на сайте несколько вариантов js (es5, es2015, es2016), и отдавать клиенту нужный файл с js, в зависимости от того, какой стандарт поддерживает его браузер. 
**Подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше проверить что поддерживает браузер клиента?**

Я сначала хотел прямо в браузере проверять, что он поддерживает, а потом соответственно подключать нужный файл js. **Но меня, беспокоит, не приведёт ли это к тому, что js начнёт выполнятся позже?** 
*Просто изначально браузер сразу начал бы загружать файл с js, а так он сначала должен дойти до кода с проверкой, выполнить его и только после этого добавить тег с подключением скрипта и браузер начнет грузить нужный js.*

**Я подумал, может такую проверку можно делать на сервере, по заголовку который приходит от клиента? Т.е. например смотреть версию юзер агента, и по ней понимать поддерживает этот браузер es2015, или нет, может есть какая нибудь php библиотека для этого?**

Comment: зачем так извращаться? если используете babel, то он все сделает за вас. У вас какая-то излишняя оптимизация, которая приводит к появлению костылей

Comment: Мне нужно поддерживать браузеры с es5 т.е. по сути ie. Большая часть кода написана в стили es2015, есть немного фичь es2016. Соответственно, сейчас babel, как я понимаю, весь мой код компилит в es5, заменяя фичи es2015 разными полифилами и т.д., соответственноб код после этого становится заметно больше, и сложнее, чем нативные фичи. Между тем, подавляющая часть браузеров уже поддерживает es2015. По этому, мне кажется, что выйгрышь, от того, что бы отдавать таким браузерам es2015, а не es5, может быть ощутимым. Или я что то не так понимаю?

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае просто делайте две сборки: под `IE` и под все остальные браузеры. Есть пакет [`babel-env`](http://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env), там можно указывать список браузеров, под которые компилится бандл. Если вы указываете новые браузеры, то `babel` не будет компилить все в `es5`, а только те вещи, которые в новых браузерах еще не поддерживаются.

Поэтому, отдельно собираете для новых браузеров, отдельно для `IE` и отдаете с сервера по условию

Как вариант еще, использовать полифилы, подгружая их только для `IE`, для этого [условные комментарии](http://htmlbook.ru/samlayout/internet-explorer/uslovnye-kommentarii) подойдут:

```
// если IE9
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src='ссылка на полифил' >
<![endif]-->
```